# solving the following equation $\sum_{k=1}^nt_k^2(\alpha_k-x)^2=\prod_{k=1}^n(\alpha_k-x)^2$

Tags: polynomials, reference-request

let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n$ be non-negative numbers and $t_1^2+t_2^2+...+t_n^2=1$ is it possible to solve this equation

$$\sum_{k=1}^nt_k^2(\alpha_k-x)^2=\prod_{k=1}^n(\alpha_k-x)^2$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: $\alpha_k$ must be a root of the polynomial of the LHS so no, there isn't a general solution for arbitrary $t_k$ and $\alpha_k$